# Range object throwing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala

In the code below, the first line compiles and executes with no result, as expected. The second one compiles as well (it should not!) and throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Why?

```
scala> 3 to 4 foreach (_ => "a")

scala> 3 to 4 foreach ("a")
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
  at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.apply(StringLike.scala:56)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.apply$(StringLike.scala:56)
  at scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString.apply(WrappedString.scala:34)
  at scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString.apply(WrappedString.scala:34)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:158)
  ... 28 elided
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code snippet, `"a"` is actually a function. Don't believe me? Let's go down the rabbit hole together.

`"a"` is a `java.lang.String`. From a Scala perspective, that type is... pretty boring. So Scala has an [implicit conversion](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#wrapString(s:String):scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString) to the [`WrappedString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/WrappedString.html) type, which your code is calling. Now, if we follow the trail of parents, we see that

```
WrappedString <: IndexedSeq[Char] <: immutable.Seq[Char] <: Seq[Char]
  <: PartialFunction[Int, Char] <: (Int) => Char
```

So `WrappedString` is actually a subclass of `(Int) => Char`. We can see the rationale for this in [the docs for `Seq`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html)

> Another way to see a sequence is as a `PartialFunction` from `Int`
>   values to the element type of the sequence. The `isDefinedAt`
>   method of a sequence returns true for the interval from `0` until `length`.

So a string (and in fact, any sequence) can behave like a function which takes a single integer index and returns that position in the sequence. So when you try to get the third (and later fourth) position in the string, you get an error.

---

As a general piece of advice, I deciphered this using a very handy compiler option. If you put the code you're asking about in a file wrapped in a minimal singleton, like so

```
object A {
  3 to 4 foreach ("a")
}
```

Then "compile" it with `scalac -print filename.scala`. You'll see something like this output

```
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // test.scala
package <empty> {
  object A extends Object {
    def <init>(): A.type = {
      A.super.<init>();
      RichInt.this.to$extension0(scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(3), 4).foreach(scala.this.Predef.wrapString("a"));
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

The important line is just after the `super` call.

```
RichInt.this.to$extension0(scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(3), 4).foreach(scala.this.Predef.wrapString("a"));
```

We see some weird magic happening to get the `3 to 4` syntax to behave, and then later on on the line we see `scala.this.Predef.wrapString`, which indicates that the `wrapString` conversion I linked to earlier is being called implicitly here. From there, it's just a matter of looking at the superclasses until you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Because the string `"a"` doesn't have any elements at index `3` or index `4`. Change the string to `"abcde"` and it won't throw that error. Change the `foreach` to `map` to see the results.